# Groovy-grails: grails run-war works, but grails run-app throws BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind<null>:80n

Tags: java, tomcat6

When I run grails -Dserver.port=80 run-app, I get

```
LifecycleException:  Protocol handler initialization failed: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind<n                                                          ull>:80
    at org.grails.tomcat.TomcatServer.start(TomcatServer.groovy:212)
    at grails.web.container.EmbeddableServer$start.call(Unknown Source)
```

When I run grails -Dserver.port=80 run-war, the web app runs perfectly.

I'm using Windows 7 and grails 1.3.7 with the built-in tomcat server. I'm new to this, so if you need more information, please ask.

How can I get run-app working on port 80?

Answer (score 0):

The exception message states that the `Address already in use`. ie. another application is already taken and is listening on port 80. If the `run-war` command works successfully, it will have taken port 80. Are you sure that this process has stopped before running the `run-app` command?

Checkout this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows) for how to investigate which process is listening on a certain port.